# Find whether a float value is within categorical value using polars dataframe

Tags: python, python-polars

I'm trying to find whether a float value "real_value" is found within the interval "categorical_value" using polars dataframe. first, I tried to cast the "categorical_value" column to categorical datatype and then find the "real_value" within the "categorical_cast"
The result should be **is_in_cat=[True,False.True]**, but I always get **[false,false,false]**

```
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({"real_value":[0.5,2.7,3.9], "categorical_value":["(0,1.1]"," 
 (1.1,2.6]","(2.6,4.5]"]}) # the response [True, False, True]
df=df.with_columns(
  pl.col("categorical_value").cast(pl.Categorical).alias("categorical_cast")
)
df = df.with_columns(
 pl.col("real_value").is_in(pl.col("categorical_cast")).alias("is_in_cat")
)      
print(df)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think categoricals work like that in Polars. Are the `(0,1.1]` strings actually coming from the result of some other operation? (`.qcut`?)

Comment: @jqurious, the string intervals are coming from a csv file. i'm casting the df column string to transform them to categorical  ```pl.col("categorical_value").cast(pl.Categorical).alias("categorical_cast")```

Comment: Ah okay. You can manually strip / split the string and cast to float then use `pl.col().is_between()` - categoricals don't offer this type of functionality as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing about categoricals that make this a more tractable problem. You just have to parse the string values, split them, and check if they're between those numbers. (btw `is_in` is used to check if a value is_in a list rather than a short way of saying is_in_between)

Anyways, here's how I'd do it.

```
df.lazy().with_columns(
    is_in_cat=(
        pl.col('categorical_cast')
        .cast(pl.Utf8)
        .str.replace_all("\(|]","")
        .str.split(',')
        .pipe(lambda mylist: (
            pl.col('real_value').is_between(mylist.list.get(0).cast(pl.Float64), 
                                            mylist.list.get(1).cast(pl.Float64)
                )
        ))
    )
).collect()

shape: (3, 4)
┌────────────┬───────────────────┬──────────────────┬───────────┐
│ real_value ┆ categorical_value ┆ categorical_cast ┆ is_in_cat │
│ ---        ┆ ---               ┆ ---              ┆ ---       │
│ f64        ┆ str               ┆ cat              ┆ bool      │
╞════════════╪═══════════════════╪══════════════════╪═══════════╡
│ 0.5        ┆ (0,1.1]           ┆ (0,1.1]          ┆ true      │
│ 2.7        ┆ (1.1,2.6]         ┆ (1.1,2.6]        ┆ false     │
│ 3.9        ┆ (2.6,4.5]         ┆ (2.6,4.5]        ┆ true      │
└────────────┴───────────────────┴──────────────────┴───────────┘
```

One note, this uses the pipe method which has the keyword lambda but don't be confused in thinking this is like an `apply`/`map_elements`. It's just a shortcut to be able to access the `list` object that preceded it twice without making a temporary column and a second `with_columns` context. By making it lazy it allows the Common SubExpression Optimization to ensure it only calcs that once and caches the result. To be honest, if it were eager, I'm not sure if it would double calc or not but if it's lazy then you can be sure (by running explain if you like) it's not double calcing.

Comment: From what I understand: the Eager API is a wrapper around the Lazy API (perhaps a DataFrame could be thought of as a LazyFrame with an implicit `.collect()` in each call) - so CSE should still be applied to the query.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for providing your code.

I am not exactly sure what is the problem with your code using `is_in`. However, as far as I can tell is_in works only with `Collections` as per the [docs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.is_in.html) which a categorical range doesn't work with. I added a new column that strips out the interval from the categorical string to values that you can use is_between for instead to do your comparison and it works. Code snippet below:

```
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "real_value":[0.5,2.7,3.9], 
    "categorical_value":["(0,1.1]","(1.1,2.6]","(2.6,4.5]"]
}) # the response [True, False, True]
df=df.with_columns(
    pl.col("categorical_value").cast(pl.Categorical).alias("categorical_cast")
)
# Parse the categorical intervals and create bounds for comparison
df = df.with_columns(
    pl.col("categorical_value")
    .apply(lambda interval: [float(val) for val in interval.strip("()[]").split(",")])
    .apply(lambda bounds: (bounds[0], bounds[1]), return_dtype=pl.Object)
    .alias("interval_bounds")
)

# Check if real_value is within the categorical interval
df = df.with_columns(
    pl.col("real_value").is_between(pl.col("interval_bounds").apply(lambda bounds: bounds[0]), pl.col("interval_bounds").apply(lambda bounds: bounds[1]))
    .alias("is_in_cat")
)

print(df)
```

Comment: `apply` is deprecated in favor of `map_batches` or `map_elements` but neither are necessary for this problem. If you're going to use that then, at the very least don't chain 2 of them, just put it in one function.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).